# Yii2 Select2 in modal searchbox is not working

Tags: ajax, yii2, bootstrap-modal

I have two yii2 projects based on kartik practical A and B. Both using johnitvn/ajaxcrudmodal. It looks like single page crud with ajax modal for create and update.

I use kartik select2 in _form.php.

However, in the project that based on practical A it can work carefully. But in the project that use practical B, it shows correctly but the searchbox is not working. It cannot be clicked and I cannot type anything on it.

I already set tabindex to false.

```
<?php
Modal::begin([
   "id" => "ajaxCrudModal",
   "footer" => "", // always need it for jquery plugin
      'size' => Modal::SIZE_DEFAULT,
      'options' => [
      'class' => 'slide',
      'tabindex' => false // important for Select2 to work properly
   ],
])
?>
<?php Modal::end(); ?>
```

Can someone help? I confused why in one project it works but not working in other project??

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: What do you have in browser console when you try to search?

Comment: Its weird. Without doing anything it is already worked. Someone has idea what happened?

Comment: @DanielAdinugroho can you fix this behavior of kartik select2?

Answer (score 0):

I update to the latest kartik library, and used below

```
<?php
Modal::begin([
    'id' => 'ajaxCrudModal',
    'footer' => '', // always need it for jquery plugin
])
?>
<?php Modal::end(); ?>
<?php $this->registerJs("$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = $.noop;"); ?>
```

It works well now

Answer (score 0):

try to set a plugin like this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'id')->widget(Select2::className(),['data'=> $data,'pluginOptions' => [
    'dropdownParent' => new yii\web\JsExpression('$("#ajaxCrudModal")'), 
]]) ?>
```